# how to move through @keyframes steps with javascript?

Tags: javascript, carousel, css-animations

I've created an image-Carouselle with `CSS-Animation @keyframes`:

```
@keyframes carouselle {
    0% { left: 0; }
    16% { left: 0; }
    33% { left: -350px; }
    49% { left: -350px; }
    66% { left: -700px; }
    84% { left: -700px; }
    100% {  left: 0; }
}
```

I've created 3 `img-buttons` which suppose to pull the image-carouselle to its `left:value`;

Whatever way I tried to relocate the `carouselle's left value` has failed.

**this didnt work for me:**

```
element.style.left = '300px';
```

I heard css-animations have higher specificity value then regularly setting properties with values.

**so I also tried this:**

```
element.style.left = '300px !important';
```

In what way can I take the carouselle position to specific step inside my `@keyframes carouselle` step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by reading this great article which will supply you with few ideas.
https://css-tricks.com/css-animation-tricks/

After that you can do one of the those things as well.

---

## `Events`

Three types of event are fired when the animation occurs:

---

### **`animationstart`**

```
# The animationstart event is fired when the animation starts for the first time.
var anim = document.getElementById("anim");
anim.addEventListener("animationstart", AnimationListener, false);
```

---

### **`animationiteration`**

```
# The animationiteration event is fired at the start of every new animation
# iteration, i.e. every iteration except the first.
anim.addEventListener("animationiteration", AnimationListener, false);
```

---

### **`animationend`**

```
 # The animationend event is fired when the animation ends.
 anim.addEventListener("animationend", AnimationListener, false);
```

---

Use the `requestAnimationFrame` to control the position of your element when you trying to animate it. The function will be called **before** it will be repainted on screen

> #### window.requestAnimationFrame()
>
> The `window.requestAnimationFrame()` method tells the browser that you wish to perform an animation and requests that the browser call a specified function to update an animation **before the next repaint**.
>
> The method takes as an argument a callback to be invoked before the repaint.